# Programmatically Check-In Files to Visual Studio Online

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I found [this](http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-version-control-items-vsi) API documentation for Visual Studio Online, which shows how to get items, but doesn't seem to show how to check in items. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

**Background:**

We are wanting to source control our Database objects (Tables, Views, Stored Procedures, etc.), but don't want to have to manually make sure the changes we make on the server are checked in to source control.

The thought is to use [Sql Scripting Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153.aspx) to generate files of the current database objects and then programmatically upload/check-in the changes to Visual Studio Online (aka TFS online). This would be performed daily on our Dev/Test/Production databases.

I'm also open to other ideas to automate this, for example if there is a way to have Visual Studio perform the check-in programmatically without needing a user to do it through the GUI.

Comment: Why don't you just treat your database the same as the rest of your source code?  Surely you expect devs to check in the changes they make to .cs or .vb files, so why is the DB source code any different?

Comment: @pm_2 that is a very good question. I think the major reason why we want to automate this instead of manually handling changes is convenience and the concern that certain changes might get overlooked. Most db object development is done in SSMS and it's kind of a hassle to have to switch to VS to generate scripts and try to remember everything you changed. This way they treat the database like the repository and source control is the backup and version control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I found out there is a [command line program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e.aspx) for Visual Studio / Team Foundation, that should [do the trick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z.aspx). I would be interested if there are other ideas out there still.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Git for VSO then [Using Git tools with Visual Studio Online](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/03/08/use-the-git-command-prompt-to-supplement-visual-studio.aspx) might help

Comment: Interesting! We don't use Git, but I'm sure there's someone out there who will find that useful